# Checking validity of postgis polygon data (imported from shapefile)

Tags: postgresql, google-maps-api-3, kml, postgis, shapefile

I'm very new to postgres/postgis so please bear with me. I've imported a shapefile using the shp2pgsql command and now I'm trying to view it to check that it has imported correctly. I've tried **SELECT ST_AsKML(geom) FROM temp2;** but it gives me the following:

```
<MultiGeometry><Polygon><outerBoundaryIs><LinearRing><coordinates>1.#INF,1.#INF 1.#INF,1.#INF 1.#INF,1.#INF 1.#INF,1.#INF 1.#INF,1.#INF 1.#INF,1.#INF 1.#INF,1.#INF 1.#INF,1.#INF 1.#INF,1.#INF 1.#INF,1.#INF 1.#INF,1.#INF 1.#INF,1.#INF 1.#INF,1.#INF 1.#INF,1.#INF 1.#INF,1.#INF 1.#INF,1.#INF 1.#INF,1.#INF 1.#INF,1.#INF 1.#INF,1.#INF 1.#INF,1.#INF 1.#INF,1.#INF 1.#INF,1.#INF 1.#INF,1.#INF 1.#INF,1.#INF 1.#INF,1.#INF 1.#INF,1.#INF 1.#INF,1.#INF 1.#INF,1.#INF 1.#INF,1.#INF 1.#INF,1.#INF 1.#INF,1.#INF 1.#INF,1.#INF 1.#INF,1.#INF 1.#INF,1.#INF 1.#INF,1.#INF 1.#INF,1.#INF 1.#INF,1.#INF 1.#INF,1.#INF 1.#INF,1.#INF 1.#INF,1.#INF 1.#INF,1.#INF 1.#INF,1.#INF 1.#INF,1.#INF 1.#INF,1.#INF 1.#INF,1.#INF 1.#INF,1.#INF 1.#INF,1.#INF 1.#INF,1.#INF 1.#INF,1.#INF 1.#INF,1.#INF 1.#INF,1.#INF 1.#INF,1.#INF</coordinates></LinearRing></outerBoundaryIs></Polygon><Polygon><outerBoundaryIs><LinearRing><coordinates>1.#INF,1.#INF 1.#INF,1.#INF 1.#INF,1.#INF 1.#INF,1.#INF 1.#INF,1.#INF 1.#INF,1.#INF 1.#INF,1.#INF 1.#INF,1.#INF 1.#INF,1.#INF 1.#INF,1.#INF 1.#INF,1.#INF 1.#INF,1.#INF 1.#INF,1.#INF 1.#INF,1.#INF 1.#INF,1.#INF 1.#INF,1.#INF 1.#INF,1.#INF 1.#INF,1.#INF 1.#INF,1.#INF 1.#INF,1.#INF 1.#INF,1.#INF 1.#INF,1.#INF 1.#INF,1.#INF 1.#INF,1.#INF 1.#INF,1.#INF 1.#INF,1.#INF 1.#INF,1.#INF 1.#INF,1.#INF 1.#INF,1.#INF 1.#INF,1.#INF 1.#INF,1.#INF 1.#INF,1.#INF 1.#INF,1.#INF</coordinates></LinearRing></outerBoundaryIs></Polygon></MultiGeometry>
<MultiGeometry><Polygon><outerBoundaryIs><LinearRing><coordinates>1.#INF,1.#INF 1.#INF,1.#INF 1.#INF,1.#INF 1.#INF,1.#INF 1.#INF,1.#INF 1.#INF,1.#INF 1.#INF,1.#INF 1.#INF,1.#INF 1.#INF,1.#INF 1.#INF,1.#INF 1.#INF,1.#INF 1.#INF,1.#INF 1.#INF,1.#INF 1.#INF,1.#INF 1.#INF,1.#INF 1.#INF,1.#INF 1.#INF,1.#INF 1.#INF,1.#INF 1.#INF,1.#INF 1.#INF,1.#INF 1.#INF,1.#INF 1.#INF,1.#INF 1.#INF,1.#INF</coordinates></LinearRing></outerBoundaryIs></Polygon></MultiGeometry>
```

Can anyone help me on where I've probably gone wrong?

Many thanks,

leddy

Comment: Thanks to @StarShip3000 I know now that the data is valid, so what I need to figure out is why I am getting the 1.#INF coordinates when using the ST_AsKML() function...?

Comment: What was the exact shp2pgsql command you ran to import the data?

Answer (score 4):

See if this helps:

http://postgis.refractions.net/docs/ST_IsValid.html

```
SELECT ST_IsValid(ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING(0 0, 1 1)')) As good_line,
       ST_IsValid(ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON((0 0, 1 1, 1 2, 1 1, 0 0))')) As bad_poly
--results
NOTICE:  Self-intersection at or near point 0 0
 good_line | bad_poly
-----------+----------
 t         | f
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have just tried the ST_IsValid and it is coming back **t** - I wonder if there is a limit to the number of coordinates you can have per polygon with ST_AsKML()...?

Comment: Can you test with a smaller poly and see if it will return false when indeed it's invalid poly and test with one that is valid to see if it returns true?